# Kernel configuration change does not stick on yocto zeus but same method works for hardknott

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto

I have two kernel configurations that I want to change in order to turn on the IPU drivers in Linux Kernel.

Kernel version is 5.4.70,
The yocto version is Zeus,

Here are some ways that I have tried,
I have opened up the configuration using `bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel`

Change the settings that I wanted to change, and then `bitbake -c diffconfig virtual/kernel`

it gave me a fragment.cfg file, I just copied it into my bbappend and then SCR_URI it.

It works the same way on the hardknot version but not on Zeus.

I have also saved the configuration of the whole kernel into .config file, then change the name of it to defconfig and copy that file using do_append, it copies the file into the kernel directory but it also does not change anything.

My change sticks until I bitbake the complete image, or until I -c clean virtual/kernel.

Below is the fragment file to know what I am trying to change

```
CONFIG_COMPILE_TEST=y
# CONFIG_ARM_CLPS711X_CPUIDLE is not set
CONFIG_ARM_BRCMSTB_AVS_CPUFREQ=y
# CONFIG_ARM_QCOM_CPUFREQ_HW is not set
# CONFIG_ARM_RASPBERRYPI_CPUFREQ is not set
# CONFIG_ARM_SCMI_CPUFREQ is not set
CONFIG_ARM_SCMI_POWER_DOMAIN=y
# CONFIG_TURRIS_MOX_RWTM is not set
# CONFIG_BCM47XX_NVRAM is not set
# CONFIG_QRTR is not set
# CONFIG_CAN_AT91 is not set
# CONFIG_CAN_SUN4I is not set
# CONFIG_PCH_CAN is not set
# CONFIG_BT_QCOMSMD is not set
# CONFIG_PCI_AARDVARK is not set
# CONFIG_PCIE_XILINX_NWL is not set
# CONFIG_PCI_TEGRA is not set
# CONFIG_PCIE_RCAR is not set
# CONFIG_PCI_V3_SEMI is not set
# CONFIG_PCIE_ROCKCHIP_HOST is not set
# CONFIG_PCIE_ROCKCHIP_EP is not set
# CONFIG_PCIE_MEDIATEK is not set
# CONFIG_PCI_EXYNOS is not set
# CONFIG_PCIE_SPEAR13XX is not set
CONFIG_PCI_KEYSTONE=y
CONFIG_PCI_KEYSTONE_HOST=y
# CONFIG_PCI_KEYSTONE_EP is not set
# CONFIG_PCI_LAYERSCAPE is not set
# CONFIG_PCI_LAYERSCAPE_EP is not set
# CONFIG_PCIE_QCOM is not set
# CONFIG_PCIE_ARMADA_8K is not set
# CONFIG_PCIE_ARTPEC6_HOST is not set
# CONFIG_PCIE_ARTPEC6_EP is not set
# CONFIG_PCIE_HISI_STB is not set
# CONFIG_PCIE_TEGRA194 is not set
# CONFIG_PCIE_UNIPHIER is not set
# CONFIG_PCIE_MOBIVEIL_PLAT is not set
# CONFIG_HISILICON_LPC is not set
# CONFIG_QCOM_EBI2 is not set
CONFIG_FSL_MC_BUS=y
# CONFIG_FSL_MC_UAPI_SUPPORT is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_BCM63XX_PARTS is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_PARSER_IMAGETAG is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_PARSER_TRX is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_SHARPSL_PARTS is not set
# CONFIG_MTD_TS5500 is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_ASPEED_SMC is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_HISI_SFC is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_NXP_SPIFI is not set
# CONFIG_OF_ALL_DTBS is not set
# CONFIG_INTEL_MID_PTI is not set
# CONFIG_ATMEL_SSC is not set
# CONFIG_QCOM_COINCELL is not set
# CONFIG_QCOM_FASTRPC is not set
# CONFIG_PCH_PHUB is not set
# CONFIG_SATA_GEMINI is not set
# CONFIG_NET_XGENE is not set
# CONFIG_NET_XGENE_V2 is not set
# CONFIG_NET_CALXEDA_XGMAC is not set
# CONFIG_CX_ECAT is not set
CONFIG_NET_VENDOR_FARADAY=y
# CONFIG_FSL_FMAN is not set
# CONFIG_FSL_ENETC is not set
# CONFIG_FSL_ENETC_VF is not set
# CONFIG_FSL_ENETC_MDIO is not set
# CONFIG_LPC_ENET is not set
# CONFIG_DWMAC_ANARION is not set
# CONFIG_DWMAC_IPQ806X is not set
# CONFIG_DWMAC_LPC18XX is not set
# CONFIG_DWMAC_MEDIATEK is not set
# CONFIG_DWMAC_MESON is not set
# CONFIG_DWMAC_OXNAS is not set
# CONFIG_DWMAC_QCOM_ETHQOS is not set
# CONFIG_DWMAC_ROCKCHIP is not set
# CONFIG_DWMAC_SOCFPGA is not set
# CONFIG_DWMAC_STI is not set
# CONFIG_DWMAC_STM32 is not set
# CONFIG_DWMAC_SUNXI is not set
# CONFIG_DWMAC_SUN8I is not set
CONFIG_NET_VENDOR_XILINX=y
# CONFIG_XILINX_AXI_EMAC is not set
# CONFIG_XILINX_LL_TEMAC is not set
# CONFIG_MDIO_ASPEED is not set
# CONFIG_MDIO_BCM_IPROC is not set
# CONFIG_MDIO_BUS_MUX_BCM_IPROC is not set
# CONFIG_MDIO_BUS_MUX_MESON_G12A is not set
# CONFIG_MDIO_MOXART is not set
# CONFIG_MDIO_SUN4I is not set
# CONFIG_MDIO_XGENE is not set
# CONFIG_BCM63XX_PHY is not set
# CONFIG_MESON_GXL_PHY is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_CLPS711X is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_EP93XX is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_GOLDFISH_EVENTS is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_ST_KEYSCAN is not set
# CONFIG_KEYBOARD_SH_KEYSC is not set
# CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_IPROC is not set
# CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_RASPBERRYPI_FW is not set
# CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_MIGOR is not set
# CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_TS4800 is not set
# CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_SUN4I is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_HISI_POWERKEY is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_SC27XX_VIBRA is not set
# CONFIG_SERIO_OLPC_APSP is not set
# CONFIG_SERIO_SUN4I_PS2 is not set
CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_DWLIB=y
# CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_BCM2835AUX is not set
# CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_LPC18XX is not set
# CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_UNIPHIER is not set
# CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_INGENIC is not set
CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_LPSS=y
CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_MID=y
# CONFIG_SERIAL_ATMEL is not set
# CONFIG_SERIAL_CLPS711X is not set
# CONFIG_SERIAL_SH_SCI is not set
# CONFIG_SERIAL_HS_LPC32XX is not set
# CONFIG_SERIAL_TIMBERDALE is not set
# CONFIG_SERIAL_BCM63XX is not set
# CONFIG_SERIAL_PCH_UART is not set
# CONFIG_SERIAL_MXS_AUART is not set
# CONFIG_SERIAL_MPS2_UART is not set
# CONFIG_SERIAL_ST_ASC is not set
# CONFIG_SERIAL_STM32 is not set
# CONFIG_SERIAL_MVEBU_UART is not set
# CONFIG_SERIAL_OWL is not set
# CONFIG_SERIAL_RDA is not set
# CONFIG_SERIAL_MILBEAUT_USIO is not set
# CONFIG_ASPEED_KCS_IPMI_BMC is not set
# CONFIG_NPCM7XX_KCS_IPMI_BMC is not set
# CONFIG_ASPEED_BT_IPMI_BMC is not set
CONFIG_HW_RANDOM_STM32=y
CONFIG_HW_RANDOM_MESON=y
CONFIG_HW_RANDOM_MTK=y
CONFIG_HW_RANDOM_EXYNOS=y
# CONFIG_I2C_HIX5HD2 is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_ASPEED is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_AXXIA is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_BCM_IPROC is not set
CONFIG_I2C_BRCMSTB=y
# CONFIG_I2C_EFM32 is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_EG20T is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_IMG is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_JZ4780 is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_LPC2K is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_MESON is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_MT65XX is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_MT7621 is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_OWL is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_RIIC is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_SH_MOBILE is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_STM32F4 is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_STM32F7 is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_SUN6I_P2WI is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_SYNQUACER is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_UNIPHIER is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_UNIPHIER_F is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_VERSATILE is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_XLP9XX is not set
# CONFIG_I2C_RCAR is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_ATH79 is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_ARMADA_3700 is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_ATMEL is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_BCM2835 is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_BCM2835AUX is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_BCM63XX is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_BCM63XX_HSSPI is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_BCM_QSPI is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_CLPS711X is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_EP93XX is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_IMG_SPFI is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_JCORE is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_LP8841_RTC is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_FSL_DSPI is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_MESON_SPICC is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_MESON_SPIFC is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_MT65XX is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_MT7621 is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_NPCM_FIU is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_NPCM_PSPI is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_LANTIQ_SSC is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_OMAP24XX is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_TI_QSPI is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_OMAP_100K is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_ORION is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_PIC32 is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_PIC32_SQI is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_RSPI is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_S3C64XX is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_SH_MSIOF is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_SH is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_SH_HSPI is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_SLAVE_MT27XX is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_SPRD is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_SPRD_ADI is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_STM32 is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_STM32_QSPI is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_ST_SSC4 is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_SUN4I is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_SUN6I is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_SYNQUACER is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_TEGRA114 is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_TEGRA20_SFLASH is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_TEGRA20_SLINK is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_TOPCLIFF_PCH is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_TXX9 is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_UNIPHIER is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_XLP is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_XTENSA_XTFPGA is not set
# CONFIG_SPI_ZYNQ_QSPI is not set
# CONFIG_SPMI_MSM_PMIC_ARB is not set
CONFIG_PTP_1588_CLOCK_DTE=y
CONFIG_PTP_1588_CLOCK_QORIQ=y
# CONFIG_PTP_1588_CLOCK_PCH is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_BM1880 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_DA850_PUPD is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_LPC18XX is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_RZA1 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_RZA2 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_RZN1 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_INGENIC is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_OWL is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_ASPEED_G4 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_ASPEED_G5 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_ASPEED_G6 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_BCM281XX is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_BCM2835 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_IPROC_GPIO is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_CYGNUS_MUX is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_NS is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_NSP_GPIO is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_NS2_MUX is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_NSP_MUX is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_AS370 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_BERLIN_BG4CT is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_NPCM7XX is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PXA25X is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PXA27X is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_APQ8064 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_APQ8084 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_IPQ4019 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_IPQ8064 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_IPQ8074 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MSM8660 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MSM8960 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MDM9615 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MSM8X74 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MSM8916 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MSM8994 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MSM8996 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MSM8998 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_QCS404 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_QCOM_SPMI_PMIC is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_QCOM_SSBI_PMIC is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_SC7180 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_SDM660 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_SDM845 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_SM8150 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_SH_PFC is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_EMEV2 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A73A4 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A7740 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A7743 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A7744 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A7745 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A77470 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A774A1 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A774C0 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A7778 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A7779 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A7790 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A7791 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A7792 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A7793 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A7794 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A7795 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A7796 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A77965 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A77970 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A77980 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A77990 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_R8A77995 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_SH7203 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_SH7264 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_SH7269 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_SH73A0 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_SH7720 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_SH7722 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_SH7723 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_SH7724 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_SH7734 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_SH7757 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_SH7785 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_SH7786 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_PFC_SHX3 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_SPRD is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_STM32F429 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_STM32F469 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_STM32F746 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_STM32F769 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_STM32H743 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_STM32MP157 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_TI_IODELAY is not set
CONFIG_PINCTRL_UNIPHIER=y
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_UNIPHIER_LD4 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_UNIPHIER_PRO4 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_UNIPHIER_SLD8 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_UNIPHIER_PRO5 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_UNIPHIER_PXS2 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_UNIPHIER_LD6B is not set
CONFIG_PINCTRL_UNIPHIER_LD11=y
CONFIG_PINCTRL_UNIPHIER_LD20=y
CONFIG_PINCTRL_UNIPHIER_PXS3=y

#
# MediaTek pinctrl drivers
#
# CONFIG_EINT_MTK is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MT2701 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MT7623 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MT7629 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MT8135 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MT8127 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MT2712 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MT6765 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MT6797 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MT7622 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MT8173 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MT8183 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MT8516 is not set
# CONFIG_PINCTRL_MT6397 is not set
# end of MediaTek pinctrl drivers

# CONFIG_GPIO_ASPEED is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_ATH79 is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_RASPBERRYPI_EXP is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_BCM_KONA is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_BRCMSTB is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_CLPS711X is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_EIC_SPRD is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_EM is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_IOP is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_LPC18XX is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_LPC32XX is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_MPC8XXX is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_MT7621 is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_PMIC_EIC_SPRD is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_RCAR is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_SNPS_CREG is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_SPRD is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_STP_XWAY is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_TEGRA is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_TEGRA186 is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_TS4800 is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_THUNDERX is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_UNIPHIER is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_VX855 is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_XLP is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_ZX is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_TS4900 is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_TQMX86 is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_AMD8111 is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_MLXBF is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_ML_IOH is not set
# CONFIG_GPIO_PCH is not set
# CONFIG_POWER_RESET_BRCMKONA is not set
# CONFIG_POWER_RESET_GEMINI_POWEROFF is not set
# CONFIG_POWER_RESET_OCELOT_RESET is not set
# CONFIG_POWER_RESET_PIIX4_POWEROFF is not set
# CONFIG_POWER_RESET_KEYSTONE is not set
# CONFIG_POWER_RESET_RMOBILE is not set
# CONFIG_POWER_RESET_ZX is not set
# CONFIG_POWER_RESET_SC27XX is not set
# CONFIG_BATTERY_ACT8945A is not set
# CONFIG_CHARGER_QCOM_SMBB is not set
# CONFIG_BATTERY_GOLDFISH is not set
# CONFIG_CHARGER_SC2731 is not set
# CONFIG_FUEL_GAUGE_SC27XX is not set
# CONFIG_SENSORS_NSA320 is not set
# CONFIG_SENSORS_RASPBERRYPI_HWMON is not set
CONFIG_HISI_THERMAL=y
# CONFIG_SPEAR_THERMAL is not set
# CONFIG_ROCKCHIP_THERMAL is not set
# CONFIG_RCAR_THERMAL is not set
# CONFIG_RCAR_GEN3_THERMAL is not set
# CONFIG_KIRKWOOD_THERMAL is not set
# CONFIG_DOVE_THERMAL is not set
# CONFIG_ARMADA_THERMAL is not set
# CONFIG_DA9062_THERMAL is not set
CONFIG_MTK_THERMAL=y

#
# Intel thermal drivers
#

#
# ACPI INT340X thermal drivers
#
# end of ACPI INT340X thermal drivers
# end of Intel thermal drivers

#
# Broadcom thermal drivers
#
# CONFIG_BCM2835_THERMAL is not set
# CONFIG_BRCMSTB_THERMAL is not set
# CONFIG_BCM_NS_THERMAL is not set
# CONFIG_BCM_SR_THERMAL is not set
# end of Broadcom thermal drivers

#
# Texas Instruments thermal drivers
#
# CONFIG_TI_SOC_THERMAL is not set
# end of Texas Instruments thermal drivers

#
# Samsung thermal drivers
#
# CONFIG_EXYNOS_THERMAL is not set
# end of Samsung thermal drivers

# CONFIG_TANGO_THERMAL is not set

#
# Qualcomm thermal drivers
#
# CONFIG_QCOM_SPMI_TEMP_ALARM is not set
# end of Qualcomm thermal drivers

# CONFIG_ZX2967_THERMAL is not set
# CONFIG_UNIPHIER_THERMAL is not set
# CONFIG_DA9052_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_DA9055_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_DA9063_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_DA9062_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_MENF21BMC_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_TANGOX_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_ARMADA_37XX_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_ASM9260_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_AT91RM9200_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_AT91SAM9X_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_SAMA5D4_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_FTWDT010_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_S3C2410_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_EP93XX_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_OMAP_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_PNX4008_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_DAVINCI_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_RN5T618_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_SUNXI_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_NPCM7XX_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_STMP3XXX_RTC_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_TS4800_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_TS72XX_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_MAX77620_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_MOXART_WDT is not set
CONFIG_SIRFSOC_WATCHDOG=y
# CONFIG_ST_LPC_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_TEGRA_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_QCOM_WDT is not set
# CONFIG_MESON_GXBB_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_MESON_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_MEDIATEK_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_DIGICOLOR_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_LPC18XX_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_ATLAS7_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_RENESAS_WDT is not set
# CONFIG_RENESAS_RZAWDT is not set
# CONFIG_ASPEED_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_UNIPHIER_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_RTD119X_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_SPRD_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_SC520_WDT is not set
# CONFIG_RDC321X_WDT is not set
# CONFIG_BCM47XX_WDT is not set
# CONFIG_BCM2835_WDT is not set
# CONFIG_BCM_KONA_WDT is not set
# CONFIG_BCM7038_WDT is not set
# CONFIG_IMGPDC_WDT is not set
# CONFIG_MPC5200_WDT is not set
# CONFIG_MV64X60_WDT is not set
# CONFIG_UML_WATCHDOG is not set
# CONFIG_MFD_SUN4I_GPADC is not set
# CONFIG_MFD_AT91_USART is not set
# CONFIG_MFD_EXYNOS_LPASS is not set
# CONFIG_MFD_MXS_LRADC is not set
# CONFIG_MFD_MX25_TSADC is not set
# CONFIG_MFD_HI655X_PMIC is not set
# CONFIG_MFD_PM8XXX is not set
# CONFIG_MFD_SPMI_PMIC is not set
# CONFIG_MFD_SC27XX_PMIC is not set
CONFIG_MFD_SUN6I_PRCM=y
# CONFIG_MFD_TIMBERDALE is not set
# CONFIG_MFD_STW481X is not set
# CONFIG_MFD_STM32_LPTIMER is not set
# CONFIG_MFD_STM32_TIMERS is not set
# CONFIG_REGULATOR_PBIAS is not set
# CONFIG_REGULATOR_QCOM_RPMH is not set
# CONFIG_REGULATOR_SC2731 is not set
# CONFIG_REGULATOR_STM32_BOOSTER is not set
# CONFIG_REGULATOR_STM32_VREFBUF is not set
# CONFIG_REGULATOR_STM32_PWR is not set
# CONFIG_REGULATOR_STW481X_VMMC is not set
# CONFIG_REGULATOR_UNIPHIER is not set
CONFIG_VIDEOBUF_GEN=y
CONFIG_VIDEOBUF_DMA_CONTIG=y
# CONFIG_VIDEO_MMP_CAMERA is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_DAVINCI_VPIF_DISPLAY is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_DAVINCI_VPIF_CAPTURE is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_DM6446_CCDC is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_DM355_CCDC is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_DM365_ISIF is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_DAVINCI_VPBE_DISPLAY is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_OMAP2_VOUT is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_SH_VOU is not set
CONFIG_VIDEO_VIU=y
# CONFIG_VIDEO_OMAP3 is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_PXA27x is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_QCOM_CAMSS is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_S3C_CAMIF is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_STM32_DCMI is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_RENESAS_CEU is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_SAMSUNG_EXYNOS4_IS is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_AM437X_VPFE is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_RCAR_CSI2 is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_RCAR_VIN is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_ATMEL_ISC is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_ATMEL_ISI is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_SUN4I_CSI is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_SUN6I_CSI is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_TI_CAL is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_MEDIATEK_JPEG is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_MEDIATEK_VPU is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_MEDIATEK_MDP is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_MEDIATEK_VCODEC is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_SAMSUNG_S5P_G2D is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_SAMSUNG_S5P_JPEG is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_SAMSUNG_S5P_MFC is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_MX2_EMMAPRP is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_SAMSUNG_EXYNOS_GSC is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_STI_BDISP is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_STI_HVA is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_STI_DELTA is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_RENESAS_JPU is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_RENESAS_FCP is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_ROCKCHIP_RGA is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_TI_VPE is not set
# CONFIG_VIDEO_QCOM_VENUS is not set
CONFIG_IMX_IPUV3_CORE=y
# CONFIG_DRM_EXYNOS is not set
# CONFIG_DRM_RCAR_DU is not set
# CONFIG_DRM_SUN4I is not set
CONFIG_DRM_IMX_IPUV3=y
# CONFIG_DRM_INGENIC is not set
# CONFIG_DRM_V3D is not set
# CONFIG_DRM_VC4 is not set
# CONFIG_DRM_MESON is not set
# CONFIG_DRM_TVE200 is not set
# CONFIG_DRM_ASPEED_GFX is not set
# CONFIG_DRM_MCDE is not set
# CONFIG_FB_CLPS711X is not set
# CONFIG_FB_GBE is not set
# CONFIG_FB_PVR2 is not set
# CONFIG_FB_ATMEL is not set
# CONFIG_FB_VIA is not set
# CONFIG_FB_PXA168 is not set
# CONFIG_FB_TMIO is not set
# CONFIG_FB_S3C is not set
# CONFIG_FB_GOLDFISH is not set
# CONFIG_FB_DA8XX is not set
# CONFIG_FB_BROADSHEET is not set
# CONFIG_FB_OMAP2 is not set
# CONFIG_SND_USB_US122L is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_ADI is not set
# CONFIG_SND_BCM2835_SOC_I2S is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_CYGNUS is not set
# CONFIG_SND_EP93XX_SOC is not set
# CONFIG_SND_JZ4740_SOC_I2S is not set
# CONFIG_SND_KIRKWOOD_SOC is not set
CONFIG_SND_SOC_INTEL_SST_TOPLEVEL=y
CONFIG_SND_SOC_INTEL_MACH=y

#
# ASoC support for Amlogic platforms
#
# CONFIG_SND_MESON_AXG_FRDDR is not set
# CONFIG_SND_MESON_AXG_TODDR is not set
# CONFIG_SND_MESON_AXG_TDMIN is not set
# CONFIG_SND_MESON_AXG_TDMOUT is not set
# CONFIG_SND_MESON_AXG_SOUND_CARD is not set
# CONFIG_SND_MESON_AXG_SPDIFOUT is not set
# CONFIG_SND_MESON_AXG_SPDIFIN is not set
# CONFIG_SND_MESON_AXG_PDM is not set
# CONFIG_SND_MESON_G12A_TOHDMITX is not set
# end of ASoC support for Amlogic platforms

# CONFIG_SND_MXS_SOC is not set
# CONFIG_SND_PXA2XX_SOC is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_QCOM is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_ROCKCHIP is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_SAMSUNG is not set

#
# SoC Audio support for Renesas SoCs
#
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_SH4_FSI is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_RCAR is not set
# end of SoC Audio support for Renesas SoCs

# CONFIG_SND_SOC_SIRF is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_SPRD is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_STI is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_STM32_SAI is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_STM32_I2S is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_STM32_SPDIFRX is not set
#
# Allwinner SoC Audio support
#
# CONFIG_SND_SUN4I_CODEC is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SUN8I_CODEC is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SUN8I_CODEC_ANALOG is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SUN50I_CODEC_ANALOG is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SUN4I_I2S is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SUN4I_SPDIF is not set
# end of Allwinner SoC Audio support

# CONFIG_SND_SOC_TEGRA is not set

#
# Audio support for Texas Instruments SoCs
#

#
# Texas Instruments DAI support for:
#
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_DAVINCI_ASP is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_DAVINCI_MCASP is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_DAVINCI_VCIF is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_OMAP_DMIC is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_OMAP_MCBSP is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_OMAP_MCPDM is not set

#
# Audio support for boards with Texas Instruments SoCs
#
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_OMAP_HDMI is not set
# end of Audio support for Texas Instruments SoCs

# CONFIG_SND_SOC_UNIPHIER is not set
# CONFIG_ZX_SPDIF is not set
# CONFIG_ZX_I2S is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_ALL_CODECS is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_JZ4740_CODEC is not set
# CONFIG_SND_SOC_JZ4725B_CODEC is not set

#
# Intel ISH HID support
#
# CONFIG_INTEL_ISH_HID is not set
# end of Intel ISH HID support
# CONFIG_USB_XHCI_HISTB is not set
# CONFIG_USB_XHCI_MTK is not set
# CONFIG_USB_XHCI_MVEBU is not set
# CONFIG_USB_XHCI_RCAR is not set
# CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD_NPCM7XX is not set
# CONFIG_USB_ISP1362_HCD is not set
# CONFIG_USB_RENESAS_USBHS is not set
```

EDITED LATER:

Here is a difference that I have found in Zeus build and Hardknott build,

In Hardknott, `hardknot_ide/build/tmp/work-shared/imx8mp-var-dart/kernel-source/` there is a hidden folder called .kernel-meta and it has all the changes that I have made, for example, if there is a repetition of any parameter in my config file or defconfig file it has logs in it.

Here is one example of the log files from that folder.

```
[INFO]: Fragments with duplicated configuration options:
    - fragment configs//./fragment.cfg has a duplicated option: CONFIG_MXC_GPU_VIV
    - fragment configs//./fragment.cfg has a duplicated option: CONFIG_STACK_TRACER
    - fragment configs//./fragment.cfg has a duplicated option: CONFIG_FTRACE_SYSCALLS
    - fragment configs//./fragment.cfg has a duplicated option: CONFIG_BLK_DEV_IO_TRACE
    - fragment configs//./fragment.cfg has a duplicated option: CONFIG_UPROBE_EVENTS
    - fragment configs//./fragment.cfg has a duplicated option: CONFIG_HIST_TRIGGERS
    - fragment configs//./fragment.cfg has a duplicated option: CONFIG_TRACE_EVENT_INJECT
    - fragment configs//./fragment.cfg has a duplicated option: CONFIG_TRACEPOINT_BENCHMARK
    - fragment configs//./fragment.cfg has a duplicated option: CONFIG_TRACE_EVAL_MAP_FILE
    - fragment configs//./fragment.cfg has a duplicated option: CONFIG_FTRACE_STARTUP_TEST
    - fragment configs//./fragment.cfg has a duplicated option: CONFIG_RING_BUFFER_STARTUP_TEST
    - fragment configs//./fragment.cfg has a duplicated option: CONFIG_PREEMPTIRQ_DELAY_TEST
    - fragment configs//./fragment.cfg has a duplicated option: CONFIG_SYNTH_EVENT_GEN_TEST
    - fragment configs//./fragment.cfg has a duplicated option: CONFIG_FTRACE
```

But there is no folder or files like this ever being made into the Zeus build, I have cleaned it and then rebuild it but still, this folder does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there have been some changes between Zeus and Hardknott so it might be related to that, regardless, several things may be happening:

- The fragement itself isnt being applied
- Kconf doesnt like your config for that kernel version and discards it
- User error

Lets check first if the fragment is being applied, the assumption is you got the fragment.cfg file somewhere where bitbake can find it and you have added it to SRC_URI_append=" file://fragment.cfg"

After that, running:

```
$ bitbake virtual/kernel -c cleansstate && bitbake virtual/kernel -c kernel_configme
```

Should clean up whatever you had, and recreate the kernel config.

Once that is done, you need to poke into the merge_config_build.log, which is the logfile for when all the fragments are being merged into the final .config.

It should be somewhere in:
/tmp/work-shared//kernel-source/.kernel-meta/cfg/merge_config_build.log

Open, that file and check that fragment.cfg is somewhere in the list of files being merged:

it should be something along these lines (this is a different kernel version but it should be similar):

```
$ cat tmp/work-shared/qemuarm64/kernel-source/.kernel-meta/cfg/merge_config_build.log 
Using .kernel-meta/configs/v5.15/ktypes/base/base.cfg as base
Merging .kernel-meta/configs/v5.15/standard/ktypes/standard/standard.cfg
Merging .kernel-meta/configs/v5.15/standard/features/kprobes/kprobes.cfg
Merging .kernel-meta/configs/v5.15/standard/features/uprobe/uprobe.cfg
Merging .kernel-meta/configs/v5.15/standard/features/utrace/utrace.cfg
```

If your fragment file is listed there, then bitbake is doing its job and your recipe looks fine, that would mean that for some reason Kconf doesnt like your new CONFIGS (likely a missing dependency or they're not compatible/valid for your kernel version).

Its also worth checking the rest of the merge_config_build.log, it may contain lines stating that Kconf specifically didnt like your configs:

```
Value requested for CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK_DBGP not in final .config
Requested value:  CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK_DBGP=y
Actual value:     

Value requested for CONFIG_TTY_PRINTK not in final .config
Requested value:  CONFIG_TTY_PRINTK=y
Actual value:
```

Lastly, there's no need to copy the .config in any appends, if you just rename it as defconfig, and add it to SRC_URI, bitbake should be able to pick it up and use it as base (it will apply fragments on top of it), you'll see it in the merge log at the very beginning as defconfig:

```
$ cat tmp/work-shared/qemuarm64/kernel-source/.kernel-meta/cfg/merge_config_build.log 
    Using <path>/defconfig as base
```

### UPDATE:

After getting more details from the updated question, its clear that this is building the Zeus branch from NXP and not directly from the Yocto Project which creates some divergence.

However, the following has been tailored to work with NXP's flow and tested to work properly:

1.- Create a config fragment, e.g. my-fragment.cfg and put it inside a linux-imx directory:

```
├── recipes-kernel                                                                                    
│   ├── linux                                                                                    
│   │   ├── linux-imx                           
│   │   │   └── my-fragment.cfg                                                                     
│   │   ├── linux-imx_5.4.bb                                                                     
│   │   └── linux-imx-headers_5.4.bb
```

2.- List such file in `SRC_URI` inside the kernel recipe so it it pulled by bitbake into the WORKDIR:

```
SRC_URI_append = " file://my-fragment.cfg"
```

3.- List the same file inside the `DELTA_KERNEL_DEFCONFIG` variable to make it work with NXP's flow:

```
DELTA_KERNEL_DEFCONFIG_prepend = "my-fragment.cfg "
```

Example file:

```
$ cat linux-imx/my-fragment.cfg
CONFIG_COMPILE_TEST=y

# Configure the kernel to look at the final .config file used
$ bitbake virtual/kernel -c configure

# Check if the required configs were merged into the kernel config
$ grep COMPILE_TEST tmp/work/imx8mpevk-poky-linux/linux-imx/5.4-r0/build/.config
CONFIG_COMPILE_TEST=y
```

Comment: This must be an old method being used in the older version of Yocto, I have tried this, but first of all, kernel_configme does not work because it is not a recognized command in Zeus. Secondly, the merge_config_build.log is not available in the work-shared folder.

Comment: please check the edited part of my question.

Comment: Looking at your edited post now I can see the MACHINE youre using is an imx8mp-var-dart, I assume you're building from NXP's sources then, possibly here:
https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/meta-imx/tree/meta-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-imx_5.4.bb?h=zeus-5.4.70-2.3.5#n63

Looks like that task NXP is using would basically discard any changes you make to the kernel config (this is the type of customization I was referring to). It sounds like you may be able to get away with putting the extra configs you need on a .config file and setting:
DELTA_KERNEL_DEFCONFIG instead of SRC_URI

Comment: Yup, they even put a comment on newer versions of the recipe:
# IMPORTANT: This task effectively disables kernel config fragments
# since the config fragments applied in do_kernel_configme are replaced.

https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/meta-imx/tree/meta-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-imx_5.10.bb?h=hardknott-5.10.72-2.2.0#n54

Comment: even this method does not work, I have tried it.

Comment: Please check the updated answer, you need the config fragment in both SRC_URI and DELTA_KERNEL_DEFCONFIG , I've tested it, it works with NXP's Zeus branch @ZBT248